# Why can't i fetch data from my SQL database, in a html document, using php?

Tags: php, html, sql, json

So I am writing a API, on the front-end it uses HTML, JS and CSS, and on the back end it uses PHP which will have access to my SQL database.

My task is once a button is clicked, create a function that will send information that is encoded in JSON off to the .php file, there I need to decode that object from JSON to PHP, then connect to the SQL database, and return relevant information encoded in JSON back to the HTML page, and later functionality will be able to update/delete certain data.

This API uses two main pages being the HTML and PHP files, along with the SQL database. Can somebody tell me why this is not working and how I can fix it? To clarify I would like to be able to select a radio button option, then press the app_list_button, which will return all Applications sorted by app_name or their review rating. Any help will be greatly appreciated and if I am able to structure anything better please let me know.

index.html

```
<div id='app_content'>
  <label>Refine search by</label>
  </br>
  <input type="radio" id="name_radio">
  <label>Name</label>
  </br>
  <input type="radio" id="rating_radio">
  <label>Rating</label>
  </br>
  <button id="app_list_button" onclick="load_list_function()">View App List</button>
  </br>
  <p id='app_list_p'></p>
  <input type="submit" name="app_detail_button" value="View App 
                Details">
  </br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
  var app_list_bttn = document.getElementById('app_list_button');
  var radio = {};
  //List apps
  function load_list_function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //name radio checked
    radio.sortByName = document.getElementById('name_radio').checked;
    //rating radio checked
    radio.sortByRating =
      document.getElementById('rating_radio').checked;

    document.getElementById('app_list_p').innerHTML = this.responseText;

    xhr.open('GET', 'API.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(radio));
  }
</script>
```

API.php

```
<?
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', '30319329', 'password', 'Application');
$errors = array();
$json_response = array();

$radio_req = file_get_contents('php://input');
$radio_result = json_decode($radio_req);

//get a list of all apps
//encode into json to send back
if ($radio_result - > sortByName == true) {
  //order by name
  $results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT app_name FROM App");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // You can modify the $row here as well, or filter out certain rows
    $json_response[] = $row;
  }
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($json_response);
} else($radio_result - > sortByRating == true) {
  //order by rating
  //order by name
  $results = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT app_name, rating FROM App, App_Review ORDER BY rating ');

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // You can modify the $row here as well, or filter out certain rows
    $json_response[] = $row;
  }

  header("Content-Type: application/json"); echo json_encode($json_response);
}
$conn - > close();
?>
```

Comment: there is a lot going on there, you need to tell us what particular piece of code is not working

Comment: the script element, sending requests to the php file. I commented most of the php out, only leaving the if and else statement. Sorry

Comment: `xhr.open('GET', 'API.php', true)` <- shouldn't that be `POST`?

Comment: Also, it's not recommended to use PHP's short-open tags. Does your environment allow `<?` instead of `<?php`?

Comment: Yes it should, I just changed it then, still nothing. Although I had tried both and accidentally left it as a GET, rather than POST. Currently I am following the structure of my laboratory using the <?php ?> tags, so I would not really know. My editor I am using is just Notepad++ it would be the latest version.

Comment: Well, how is it *"not working"*? You appear to be missing the typical XHR `onreadystatechange` or `onload` function so you're never doing anything when the request completes

Comment: Also, `else ($radio_result->sortByRating == true)` is invalid syntax. You really need to take the time to check your code properly

Comment: Alright I will try adding one of those functions then, Thankyou. Yes I am a very new learner passing this data, this task was a big step up out of my ordinary tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is this:

```
file_get_contents('php://radio');
```

That will not give you anything, it needs to be:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Also, when you do:

```
document.getElementById('app_list_p').innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

you are setting the innerHTML before you've even done the ajax request - `this` in this context is the window, so `this.responseText` will always be undefined.
You need to do it more like:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        document.getElementById('app_list_p').innerHTML =xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just gave it a try then, but it still seems the problem persists. When I click the app list button with a radio button selected it will return "undefined"